# Функции вывода в Си

Tags: c, printf, std

при использовании  printf("Hello world") ,  всё что в кавычках, находится в потоке stdout?

Comment: Именно так, в stdout

Answer (score 0):

Функции семейства f записывают строку в любой открытый поток (параметр stream), в частности, в стандартные потоки вывода (stdout, stderr). fprintf(stdout, format, …) эквивалентно printf(format, …).

Источник:
Wiki: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf